# How to show error on view after file uploaded by user exceeds the size limit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, html

I have a requirement where user uploads photo and I need to display error message on the view when file size exceeds 2mb. The challenge I have is size of photo cannot be known unless its fully uploaded.(If it can be, please let me know).So once file is uploaded I have lost my view, so in order to show message on the same view what should I do ? or if I can show message through some Jquery pop up,that will suffice the need as well(but how to call it from mvc controller? Can we check file size on client side once the user clicks submit button  ).How to go ahead with this?

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(BackgroundImage image)
    {
        if (image != null && image.File.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(image.File.FileName);
            if (image.File.ContentLength > 2080)
            {
              // need to show error on view or show pop message on client side
            }


            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/images"), fileName);
            image.File.SaveAs(path);
        }

        return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "ItemDataPhoto", new { id = image.backGroundId });
    }
```

Comment: I use DropzoneJS, which allows you to know the filesize prior to upload. you can display error messages without uploading the files (you can also check the files are photos and not other file formats). http://www.dropzonejs.com/

Comment: Add a `ModelStateError` and return the view. But you can also use a validation attribute so that you get client and server side validation. Refer [Client-side File Upload Size Validation in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.bradwestness.com/2014/09/24/client-side-file-upload-validation/) for an example

Answer (score 0):

You can add an error to model state and return the view.

```
if (image.File.ContentLength > 2080)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty,"File size is too big");
    return View();
}
```

Make sure you are using the `ValidationSummary` helper in your view to display the error message.

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false)
```